# Running JBehave from gradle?

Tags: groovy, junit, gradle, jbehave

Is there a way to run JBehave from gradle? I currently have a `JUnitStories` subclass that sets a step class and overrides `storyPaths` to point at different `.story` files.

This task can supposedly do what I need, but I'm not sure how I integrate it with what I have.

```
task spec << {
    ant.taskdef(
            name: 'jbehave',
            classname: 'org.jbehave.ant.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables',
            classpath: configurations.jbehave.asPath)

    ant.jbehave(
            includes: 'src/main/specs',
            generateViewAfterStories: true
    )
}
```

How do I get this running from a gradle task with my stories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `JBehave` plugin for Gradle. If JBehave has JUnit integration, you can run JBehave tests via Gradle's `test` task. Otherwise, the task above looks fine too. Apparently it expects JBehave sources in `src/main/specs` (I don't know if they need to be compiled). It also expects a `jbehave` configuration containing the JBehave library. You can set it up like so:

```
configurations { jbehave }
dependencies {
    jbehave ...
}
```

Comment: This can definitely run with gradle test, it seems, but now I need to figure out how to get JBehave to load a number of spec tests as individual JUnit tests for proper reporting. The "gradle" piece of this is solved, though, so I'm marking this as the answer.